# What is the correct way to apply css on php echo?

Tags: php, css

How can I apply css on my echoes below? I got it to work before I added the header for UTF encoding but now it echoes the css too so my echo result was: `<p align='center'>Good!!!</p>`

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$answer = $_POST['1'];  
if ($answer == "YES") {          
    echo 'Good!!!';      
}
else {
    echo 'Try Again!';
} 
?>
```

**CORRECTED:**

```
<?php 
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $answer = $_POST['1'];  
    if ($answer == "YES") {          
        echo "<p align='center'>Good!!!</p>";        
    }
    else {
        echo "<p align='center'>Try Again!</p>";  
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Do you know what `Content-type: text/plain` does? Even if you don't, if it was working before that means this change broke it. So Google and find out why.

Comment: This code never echoed `<p align...`

Comment: Why do you set the header to text/plain? It doesn't make much sense, but at least change it to `text/html`

Comment: CSS? You mean HTML? I'm confused...

Comment: Didn't know text/plain disables html yeah. No need to downvote like mad though guys.

Answer (score 1):

You're sending the header:

```
Content-type: text/plain;
```

which tells the browser that the incoming data is plain text, and not html so any markup in the returned data is ignored.